# DOCKERFILE, Attirbutes in it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I dont really understand what is WORKDIR
I have seen many sources by no one says exactyly where is that WORKDIR
I am using Windows

WORKDIR /usr/src/my_app_directory
Here is the sample from one website, it says that my workdir is  /usr/src/my_app_directory.
Can I write anything as my workdir if yes where is that workdir?

Comment: it's the current working directory like when you cd into a folder. eg. `cd /tmp` ->means `/tmp` is your current working directory.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

Comment: is thi directory inside of my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply it used to change the default working directly of the container e.g. The directory you are logged into when you first connect or start the container.

Comment: can i use any directory?

Comment: Should imagine so unless its locked down with file permissions.